# Вывод текста в две колонки

Tags: php

Подскажите как вывести содержимое в две колонки?

```
<div class='list_city text-center'>
<?php
    while($el = $rsData->fetch()){
        foreach($el as $key => $value){
            ?>
               <div style="float:<?php echo ($key%2) ? 'right' : 'left'; ?>">
                   <?php echo $value; ?>
               </div>
            <?
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Вар дамп `$el` выдаёт следующую структуру

```
array(1) { ["UF_NAME"]=> string(14) "Москва" } 
array(1) { ["UF_NAME"]=> string(14) "Санкт-Петербург" } 
array(1) { ["UF_NAME"]=> string(16) "Белгород" } 
array(1) { ["UF_NAME"]=> string(12) "Брянск" }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $key = 0;
    while($el = $rsData->fetch()){
        ?>
           <div style="display:inline">
               <?php echo $el['UF_NAME']; ?>
           </div>
        <?
        if ($key%2 != 0) echo '<br>';
        $key++;

    }
?>
```

Comment: не помогло.......

Comment: Измениллллллллл

Comment: теперь при выводе каждый элемент обвёрнут в див, "эффекта" вывода в две колонки не наблюдается

Comment: последняя попытка :)

Comment: спасиб), а как сделать такой вариант: половину вывести в одной колонке, а оставшуюся половину в другой?

Answer (score 0):

А такой вариант не подойдет?

```
<?php
$arr = [];
while($el = $rsData->fetch()) {
  $arr[] = $el["UF_NAME"];
}
    $left = array_filter($arr, function ($key) { return $key % 2 === 0;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $right = array_diff($arr, $left);
?>
<div style="float: left;">
  <?php echo join("\n", array_map(function ($v) { return '<div>' . $v . '</div>'; }, $left)); ?>
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
<?php echo join("\n", array_map(function ($v) { return '<div>' . $v . '</div>'; }, $right)); ?>
</div>
```